# Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN database at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete]

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker

I'm creating an api using docker, postgresql, and nodejs (typescript). I've had this error ever since creating an admin user and nothing seems to be able to fix it:

Error in docker terminal:

```
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN database
   at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:72:26)
[ERROR] 12:33:32 Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN database
```

Error in Insomnia:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "message": "Internal server error - Cannot inject the dependency \"categoriesRepository\" at position #0 of \"ListCategoriesUseCase\" constructor. Reason:\n    No repository for \"Category\" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current \"default\" connection?"
}
```

I'm following an online course and this same code seems to work for everyone else since there are no reports of this error in the course's forum.

From what I've gathered it seems to be some type of problem when connecting to my database, which is a docker container. Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
    version: "3.9"

services:
  database_ignite:
    image: postgres
    container_name: database_ignite
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=something
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=something
      - POSTGRES_DB=rentx
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/data/postgres

  app:
    build: .
    container_name: rentx
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - 3333:3333
      - 9229:9229
    volumes: 
      - .:/usr/app
    links: 
      - database_ignite
    depends_on:
      - database_ignite

volumes:
  pgdata:
    driver: local
```

My server.ts file:

```
import "reflect-metadata";

import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import "express-async-errors";
import swaggerUi from "swagger-ui-express";

import { AppError } from "@shared/errors/AppError";
import createConnection from "@shared/infra/typeorm";

import swaggerFile from "../../../swagger.json";
import { router } from "./routes";

import "@shared/container";

createConnection();
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api-docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerFile));

app.use(router);

app.use(
    (err: Error, request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        if (err instanceof AppError) {
            return response.status(err.statusCode).json({
                message: err.message,
            });
        }

        return response.status(500).json({
            status: "error",
            message: `Internal server error - ${err.message}`,
        });
    }
);

app.listen(3333, () => console.log("Server running"));
```

And this is my index.ts file, inside src>modules>shared>infra>http>server.ts:

```
import { Connection, createConnection, getConnectionOptions } from "typeorm";

export default async (host = "database"): Promise<Connection> => {
    const defaultOptions = await getConnectionOptions();

    return createConnection(
        Object.assign(defaultOptions, {
            host,
        })
    );
};
```

I've tried restarting my containers, remaking them, accessing my postgres container and checking the tables, I've switched every "database" to "localhost" but it's the same every time: the containers run, but the error persists. I've checked the course's repo and my code matches. I've flushed my DNS and that also did nothing.

Here's the admin.ts file that "started it all":

```
import { hash } from "bcryptjs";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

import createConnection from "../index";

async function create() {
    const connection = await createConnection("localhost");

    const id = uuidv4();
    const password = await hash("admin", 6);

    await connection.query(`
    INSERT INTO Users (id, name, email, password, "isAdmin", driver_license, created_at)
    VALUES (
      '${id}',
      'admin',
      'admin@rentx.com.br',
      '${password}',
      true,
      '0123456789',
      NOW()
    )
  `);

    await connection.close;
}

create().then(() => console.log("Administrative user created"));
```

I would love to know what is causing this error.

Comment: I've seen a couple of questions where the obsolete `links:` option causes networking problems like this.  Does deleting the `links:` block help?  (You don't need to replace it with anything; in Compose files version 2 or 3, containers can automatically connect to each other using their Compose service names.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I commented the `links:` out, but unfortunatly the same error still occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a service named `database_ignite` in your `docker-compose.yml` file. Docker by default creates a host using the name of your service. Try changing your host from `database` inside your `index.ts` file to `database_ignite`:

```js
import { Connection, createConnection, getConnectionOptions } from "typeorm";

export default async (host = "database_ignite"): Promise<Connection> => {
    // Changed database to ^^ database_ignite ^^

    const defaultOptions = await getConnectionOptions();

    return createConnection(
        Object.assign(defaultOptions, {
            host,
        })
    );
};
```